# Game Menu HTML & JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have been asked to make an open game dialogue on a HTML game via jQuery but the issue I am having is I am not allowed to change the code within the body, so I'm relying on jQuery.

I have created a semi-transparent background and I am trying to implement a button which when pressed the overlay disappears but i'm having issues making the button work.

JavaScript:

```
function GameMenu()
    {
        $('body').prepend('<button id="Button1">Start Game</button>');
        // Create dialog component
        $('body').prepend('<div id="But”></div>');
        // Create stop interaction division
        $('body').prepend('<div id="Overlay"></div>');
        // Apply stop interaction styling
        $("#Overlay").addClass("Overlay");
    }
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // Set button click listener
        $('#Button1').on('click', function(){
            Overlay(1, "Information", "info.png",
                "This is some information", "white");

        });
    });
```

CSS

```
    .Overlay {
             position: absolute;
             width: 1112px; 
             height: 556px; 
             background-color: grey;
             opacity: 0.7;
             z-index:900;
             }
    #initDialog1 {
                 position: relative;
                 z-index:1000;
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding your click event on document ready but the button most likely hasn't yet been added to the DOM.

This should work (assuming that you are defining your `Overlay` function somewhere)...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        // Set button click listener
        $('body').on('click', '#Button1', function(){

            $('#Overlay').hide(); // Hide the overlay element

            // What is this function doing?...
            Overlay(1, "Information", "info.png",
                "This is some information", "white");

        });
    });
```

Comment: if it try `{
   // Create dialog component
   $('body').prepend('<div id="Button1”></div>');
   // Create stop interaction division
   $('body').prepend('<div id="Overlay"></div>');
   // Apply stop interaction styling
   $("#Button1").addClass("Overlay");
  }
  $( document ).ready(function() {
        // Set button click listener
        $('body').on('click', '#Button1', function(){
            Overlay(1, "Information", "info.png",
                "This is some information", "white");

        });
    });` the button and overlay disappear

Comment: Changing the click binding as I suggested wouldn't make anything disappear. Your problem must be elsewhere

Comment: Can you set up an example on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Okay that was my fault nothing has disappeared but when i click the button nothing happens the overlay is still there

Comment: There is nothing in your code that attempts to hide the overlay. You probably want to add something like `$('#Overlay').hide();` inside your button click handler -- see update . Also, what is your `Overlay` function doing? and where is it defined?